# I want to use a global variable to "save" the session of a user, in a controller file

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a web application on some courses in which I need to save a field (username) throughout the session of the user that is logged in, then in another part when the user finishes the course and clicks on the "Accept" button, the progress is saved in a field in the database.

If I ask the user previously to introduce the field and click on "Accept", I pick it up and I treat it in the function of the `ModifyProgress` controller, this does work for me, but I need not to ask that field from the user. That is, only by entering your name once in the login, you can already treat that variable throughout the application.

I tried a typical global variable at the beginning of the controller file, and I assign it to the field `(GlobalUserName = $scope.username)` but it is only stored in the Login function. When I try to use in other function I get a "undefined" alert in the chrome console (f12).

```
 var app = angular.module('gestionUsuarioCurso');
 app.controller('usuariosCursoController',
    function($scope,$http,usuariosCursoService) {

        gestionUsuarioCurso = this;

        gestionUsuarioCurso.progresoUsuario;

        gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario;

        gestionUsuarioCurso.curso;

        gestionUsuarioCurso.usuarios = [];
        gestionUsuarioCurso.status;

        GlobalUsername;

        this.progresoUsuario = 0;

        this.selectProgreso = function (){

            return this.progresoUsuario;

        };

        $scope.LoginUsuario = function(){
            usuariosCursoService.loginUser(
               $scope.userName,$scope.password).then(function(usuario){

                  Globalusername = $scope.userName;

                  gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario = usuario;

                  console.log(GlobalUsername);  //This shows it correctly

                      .......
```

With the `$scope.userName` I get the username and I can treat it in that function, but if I want to use it now in this other function of `ModifyProgress`, it appears to me by the debug console (f12 in chrome) undefined that field.

The `showUser` method (within ModifyProgress) tries to find a user in the bbdd with the username field, in this case the user passes it to them by hand.

```
$scope.ModifyProgress = function(FinishedCourse){

    //console.log(GlobalUsername);  //Undefined on console

    usuariosCursoService.showUser(GlobalUsername).then(function(usuario) {

        //console.log(GlobalUsername);  //Undefined on console 

        gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario = usuario;

            .........
```

I would like the variable `GlobalUsername` to "travel" with the value obtained on the `LoginUser` function to another functions with that value, and so that the value can go through webpages.

Comment: use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` for global variables!

Comment: Please edit you question and please add code in proper format. For more information see  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` for global variables!

`$rootScope.GlobalUsername = 'Your name!!';`

[Read More about $rootScope](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that, I declare a variable (this.Username) and then I use the "$rootScope" but if failed: do you refere to this?                                                   
                $scope.LoginUsuario = function(){

                                usuariosCursoService.loginUser($rootScope.nombreUsuario,$scope.password).then(function(usuario){
                                               
                                                UserName = $rootScope.nombreUsuario;

                                                console.log(UserName);

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to create a new service.

Services are singletons and passed to your controller by reference.
So you could inject it int your first controller to store the value and inject in your other controller to retrieve this value.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

You could use `$rootScope` in order to have it available anywhere but it's not recommended.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope for more details on what scopes are made for.